# Gaming - MBP runs too hot

Tags: macbook-pro, cooling

When I play Diablo 3 on my MBP (late 2011) the computer gets unbelievably hot.

It gets to be too hot to touch near where the screen connects to the keyboard.

I get the feeling like this is terrible for the computer.

I put an external cooling pad underneath it, but it doesn't really help that much.

I also have an app called "IStat Menus by Bjango" which controls the fans.

I stopped using the software a while ago, but it is an option and it is legitimate.

Is there any way I can help it cool down, or should I just buy a computer specific for gaming?

I found a real good [ARTICLE](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2773197?start=0&tstart=0) on the subject.

[image: Specs on my mac]

Comment: What is 'hot' in degrees?

Comment: @CousinCocaine 80-90 C w/ a cooling pad underneath

Comment: Measured on the chip? If so, these are no abnormal temperatures.

Comment: yeah, measured from the cpu

Comment: MBP's are known to run hot. Some say it is due to too much cool paste. I just bought a Playstation for gaming, solved it for me.

Comment: haha, you think I should stop using it or does it matter? Maybe just point some external fans at it?

Comment: You didn't specify exactly the type of processor but you can easily look up the max operating temperature for your CPU.

Comment: @Hefewe1zen I added an image of the system specs

Comment: I don't recommend using a third party app to control your fans. It's not needed.

Comment: @PeterCampanelli that's what I was thinking too

Comment: These temps are fine. Modern CPU's slow down automatically when becoming too hot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[As per Intel's site](http://ark.intel.com/products/53470/Intel-Core-i7-2675QM-Processor-6M-Cache-up-to-3_10-GHz), the maximum temperature for this CPU is 100 C.  I wouldn't be immediately concerned unless your machine is freezing / shutting down, or showing video artifacts.

Obviously 80 C is still pretty warm; you can try some things to bring it down.

- Active cooling pad/base with fans built in
- Cleaning out the CPU fan and exhaust vents.  This
  requires taking off the bottom cover.
- Using iStats or another program to run the fan at a higher speed.

Comment: Do you think IStat is safe to use?

Comment: iStat is reliable software